Cauchy repeated integration formula - limits infinity
There is some formula for repeated integration with the following limits:
$$\int _z^{\infty }\text{..}\int _z^{\infty }\int _z^{\infty }\int _z^{\infty }f(z) (dz)^n$$
Integrate[(E^(z^2/(4*x))*Sqrt[Pi]*Erfc[z/(2*Sqrt[x])])/(2*
    Sqrt[x]), {z, z, Infinity}]

This is the integral that I try to calculate n times but it seems to diverge.

You use $z$ both to mean several integration variables and integration limits. Can you please re-write your expression more clearly (by using different variable names like $z_1$, $z_2$, ...) so that it becomes easier to help you? Concretely, your ..., {z, z, Infinity}] shows the problem that you are double-using the variable z.

@Roman the formula is correct is the Laplace transformation of the function t^n f[t] where f[z] it is his Laplace trasnformation.

@capea as Roman advises could you provide clarification. The way you specify the integral in MMA will not work, even without considerations of divergence. Further, please look at the answer you accepted again. For example, for real x >0, the second term vanishes ($\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}-1=0$) and argument suggested collapses. I am just suggesting some clarification if you still are pondering this question.

Indeed, the integral under cosideration diverges at infinity, as
Series[(E^(z^2/(4*x))*Sqrt[Pi]*Erfc[z/(2*Sqrt[x])])/(2*Sqrt[x]), 
{z, Infinity, 1}] // Normal


$$ \frac{1}{z}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}
   \sqrt{x}-1\right) e^{\frac{z^2}{4 x}}}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$

shows.

there would be some formula like Cauchy's to calculate the repeated integral with variable changes??

@capea: I don't know such a formula.Maybe, the Riemann-Lioulille integral would be helpful to this end.
